# Find each word in a sentence in MIPS assembly

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, mips

I am trying to learn MIPS and I want to write a programme that will ask the user for an input sentence and then print out each word from it on a new line. The condition is that when there is a character such as ',', ' ', '.', '-' it should go to the next number or letter without printing the punctuation signs.

I find it difficult to check each element from the string to see whether it is a delimiting character or a normal character and then print out the result. Can someone please explain how to do this without too many complications? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You coould have a string with all the delimiter chars and write a routine that returns true if a given character can be found in that string. Or you could have a table with 256 entries where the character code would be used as an index, so you'd set all entries corresponding to delimiters to non-zero, and the rest to zero (or vice versa).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. How do I write a routine as in the first option? I need to do this as simple as possible.

Comment: How would you write the program in `C`? That's usually a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is write a string tokenizer. This is commonly the first step in writing many text analyzers including compilers. For my pseudo code, I'm assuming the text the user entered is in a variable named "s".

```
int i = 0;
int l = strlen( s );

while( i < l )
{
  int start = i;   // Will need the start address later

  // Scan forward in 's' until a delimiter is found
  while( i < l && s[i] != ',' && s[i] != '.' && s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '-' )
  {
    i += 1;
  }

  if( i == start )
  {
    i += 1;
    continue;  // Multiple delimiters
  }

  s[i] = 0;         // Replace the delimiter with null.
  print &s[start];  // Standard out
  i += 1;           // Move to the next character
}
```